# Query for exact match of jsonb column in Rails 5 and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

In my Rails 5 app with a Postgres database, I have a model `Post` with `jsonb` column called `comments`. The default value for `comments` is `{}`.

I would like to return the count of `posts` that have the default value for `comments`.

When I run `Post.where("comments @> ?", {}.to_json).count` I get a count of every record in the `Post` table.

Is there a query which would only return exact matches so I could know the number of `posts` that have no comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my Rails 5 app with a Postgres database, I have a model Post with jsonb column called comments. The default value for comments is {}.

Let's say this is your table:

```
CREATE TABLE Posts
(
    post_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    comments jsonb DEFAULT '{}'   /* or json instead of jsonb */
) ;
```

... some sample data

```
INSERT INTO Posts
   (comments)
VALUES
   ('{"something": "a comment"}'),
   ('[{"something": "a comment"}, {"something":"another comment"}]'),
   (DEFAULT),
   ('{}'),
   (DEFAULT),
   (NULL) ;
```

... that looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts;
```

```
post_id | comments                                                      
------: | :-------------------------------------------------------------
      1 | {"something": "a comment"}                                    
      2 | [{"something": "a comment"}, {"something": "another comment"}]
      3 | {}                                                            
      4 | {}                                                            
      5 | {}                                                            
      6 | null
```

> I would like to return the count of posts that have the default value for comments.

This is as simple as comparing the `comments` column (for equality) with `{}`:

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    posts
WHERE
    comments = '{}'   /* or '{}'::jsonb */
```

```
| count |
| ----: |
|     3 |
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2accc4639808c4e14a15d0bdc90dd217)*

---

My *guess* (I haven't tried) is that you translate this into rails with:

```
Post.where("comments = ?", {}.to_json).count
```

Comment: Weirdly, the following doesn't work: `Post.where(comments: {}.to_json).count`